# Latex won't end compiling when multicolumn and S-type is used in tabular

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the problem that Latex won't end processing when I use a table with some `S`-types AND multicolumn, which should not be `S` but `l`. When I comment the multicolum out, Latex will finish compiling. Does anyone have an idea where the problem is and how to obtain the multicolumn AND `S` in `\begin{tabular}{lSSSSSSSr}`?

```
%Warning if deprecated LaTeX construct is used
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}

%Definition des Dokumentes
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

%Schriftart Arial - ACHTUNG: Compile with XeLaTeX (not PDFLaTeX)!
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale = 1.0]

%Seitenlayout
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry} %showframe

%Deutsche Umlaute, Englisch, griechische Symbole
\usepackage[main = ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}

%Kopfzeile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Fußzeile
\usepackage[hang, multiple]{footmisc}

%Graphiken und Bilder
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{grffile}

%Tabellenumgebung
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} %\toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}

%Captions
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf, format=hang, font=footnotesize, position=bottom}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf, format=hang, font=footnotesize, position=top, skip=4pt, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%Listenumgebung
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

%Mathematische Symbole und Zeichen
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[locale          = DE, %Komma als Dezimaltrennzeichen, Punkt als Tausendertrennzeichen (automatische Anzeige)
            group-minimum-digits = 4, %Komma schon bei 4 Ziffern            
            group-separator = {.} %Punkt als Tausendertrennzeichen
            ]{siunitx} %SI-Einheiten

%Algorithm Package - für Code, Pseudocode, Algorithmen
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

%Anführungszeichen
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}

%Punkte über Buchstaben im Textmode
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\textdot[1]{\stackon[1pt]{#1}{.}}

%Farben
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%Links, Bookmarks, Metadata
\usepackage[bookmarks       = true,
            bookmarksopen   = true,
            unicode         = true,
            pdfdisplaydoctitle,   
            colorlinks      = true,
            linkcolor       = black,
            citecolor       = black,
            urlcolor        = black
            ]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{sf}

%Anhang
\usepackage{appendix}

%To-Do-Listen
\usepackage[textsize=scriptsize, textwidth=22mm, backgroundcolor = Dandelion!80, linecolor=Dandelion, bordercolor=Dandelion]{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.4cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1.5mm}


% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Literaturverzeichnis und Zitationen
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

%Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[style           = alphabetic-verb,
            backend         = biber,
            maxbibnames     = 2,
            minbibnames     = 2,
            maxalphanames   = 1,
            minalphanames   = 1,
            useeditor       = false,
            giveninits      = true
            ]{biblatex}

%Name, V.
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 

%Doppelpunkt nach letztem Verfasser
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\addspace} 

%Änderungen von Strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
                andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}, %et al.
                urlseen   = {Abruf\addcolon}, %Anpassung in "Abruf:" bei URLs
                references   = {Literaturverzeichnis},
                bibliography = {Literaturverzeichnis},
                mathesis = {Masterarbeit}
                }

%Kapitälchen Nachame und Vorname von Autoren in Bibliografie und in Zitationen
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}
\def\ifmknamesc{\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{author}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\textsc{#1}}

%Komma bei mehreren Quellen in Zitation
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

%Semikolon bei mehreren Autoren
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
}

%Formatierung von Regular Database Entry Types
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\textit{#1\isdot}}

%Formatierung von Zitation bei mehreren Autoren
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

%Formatierung von DIN/ VDI Entries
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate[dinvdi]{\labelelement{\field{note}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{dinvdi}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printlist{location}
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}
  \printlist{organization}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printdate
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [dinvdi]
  {booktitleaddon}{\textsc{#1}}




% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
% Abstände und Platzierungen
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

%Überschriftenanzeige und -platzierung im Text
\usepackage[clearempty]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{0}\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{9pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0}\bfseries}{\thesection}{9pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{0}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{9pt}{}

%Abstand zwischen Absätzen
\usepackage[skip=6pt plus 4pt minus 4pt]{parskip}

%Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{leading}
\leading{21pt}

%Abstände Überschriften
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-22pt plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}{2pt plus .1ex}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{30pt plus 0.7ex minus .15ex}{13pt plus .1ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{28pt plus 0.7ex minus .15ex}{11pt plus .1ex}

%Formatierung Inhaltsverzeichnis
\usepackage[notindex, nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{2em}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[21pt]{\addvspace{15pt plus .2pt}\bfseries}{20pt}{9.5pt}
\dottedcontents{section}[50pt]{\addvspace{3pt plus .2pt}}{2.3em}{9.5pt}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[89pt]{\addvspace{3pt plus .2pt}}{3.2em}{9.5pt}

%add stretchable glue (Overfull-/ & Underfull-\hbox-Warnings)
\usepackage{microtype}
\emergencystretch=1em











% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
%
%
% Anfang von Dokumententext
%
%
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[th]
\caption[Caption]{Caption.} \label{tab:Caption}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lSSSSSSSr} 
    \toprule
    {} & {Eins} & {Zwei} & {Drei} & {Vier} & {Fünf} & {Sechs} & {Sieben} & {} \\
    \midrule
    {Energiebedarf} & 100,00 & 200,00 & 200,00 & 200,00 & 100,00 & 100,00 & 200,00 & {} \\[-2.5mm]
    {[Einheit]} & {} & {} & {}  & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\

    {Energiebedarf}  & 10,00 & 20,00 & 20,00 & 20,00 & 10,00 & 10,00 & 20,00 & {} \\[-2.5mm]
    {Jahresmittel}  & {}  & {} & {}  & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\[-2.5mm]
    {[Einheit]} & {}  & {} & {}  & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\

    \midrule
    \midrule
    {\multicolumn{8}{l}{Summe Energiebedarf pro Jahr [Einheit]}} & {2.000,00} \\

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated but please keep in mind that `hyperref` should (with a few exceptions)  be the last package in your preamble. I also recomment to not use `resizebox` on a tabular to make it fit into the textwidth as this will ead to inconsistent fonz sizes throughtout your document. There are better methods (such as manually selecting an appropriate font size, changing the white space betwwen columns and using an appropriate `table-fromat` option for your `S` type columns.

Comment: Most likely the issue is caused by the set of `{}` around the `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder regarding `hyperref`, as my document expanded I frogot about this. I am also looking into the `resizebox`-issue, I postponed this a bit. The hint with the brackets worked - great, thanks! (If you write this as an answer I will gladly be able to accept it.)

Comment: the title of this question is very misleading. saying it does not end, on the contrary latex stops and gives an error message at the misplaced `\multicolumn`:  `! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
`  If you scroll past an error, then any behaviour is expected.

Comment: Interesting, in my case my computer wouldn't end compiling unless I interrupted Latex on purpose. Nonetheless I am happy that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document can be made compilable by removing the set of `{}` around the `\multicolumn` command.